# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources related to the English language
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/10004).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2018](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/community-promotion-ads-2018)

Answer (score 21):

[image: English Language Learners]

Comment: What about **"Are you learning the English language? Come visit English Language Learners"**? It may just be me, but it sounds weird to say "English Language Learner" twice in a row.

Comment: I took the image from last year. feel free to update it.

Comment: My mistake, then. I don't have the means to, but it may not be worth it without the original layered image.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Explore the roots of English at the Latin Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Interested in applications of language?]

Comment: Hm. Can you choose one of the other ads from [this post](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/lets-design-an-ad-for-our-site)? A user has raised [some issues](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/481) regarding this particular ad.

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks for letting me know; fixed.

Comment: The above comments have been flagged as suitable for deletion: I disagree as the references to the Meta.Lit discussion on how to advertise that site (with particular reference to Ezra Pound but generally applicable) are valuable.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Language Learning Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Come to Writer's Chat]

Comment: This image is used with permission from its creator, Michelle Maule, who has wonderful things for sale on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/shop/michelemaule?ref=pr_shop_more).

Answer (score 7):

[image: Language Learning Stack Exchange]

Comment: Note that [another Language Learning SE ad](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/10017/53711) currently has enough votes.

Comment: @Nathaniel Is that an issue?

Comment: I'm not aware of a rule against two ads promoting the same thing, but personally I think it's excessive, and thus worth noting for others who may agree with me.

Comment: @Nathaniel Duly noted.

Answer (score 4):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Copied from last year.

Comment: (It is dynamic)

Answer (score 4):

[image: For all those single-word-request word-smiths]

Answer (score 3):

[image: No general reference, please!]

Comment: Ha! How's that a promotion ad?

Comment: From the question: "For example, you might promote the following things: ... useful tools or resources related to the English language"

Answer (score 1):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score -1):

[image: Join the Interpersonal Skills site proposal]

Comment: This site is for lots of those "What should I say in this situation?" questions which are off-topic here.

Comment: "What should I say in ____ situation?" Isn't a good question for any site on the network as it's a polling/opinion-based question.

Comment: @catija Not if it's asking for conventional conversion components, which is how a lot of these questions function at IPS

Comment: That's not in any way representative of the sorts of questions asked here or on ELL... which generally come from people who simply don't know the idiomatic phrasing.