# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources related to the English language
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11167).

Comment: Last year's: [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10004/53711)

Comment: Guys, while I like the idea of promoting related sister sites, I don’t want ELU’s sidebar completely filled with ads for them for the next year. Please consider adding answers promoting English resources that will help our target audience. Meta members can’t vote for ads which aren’t there, and absent them all we will get is ads for non-English resources which may be interesting to our target audience, but not directly assist them with their needs.

Comment: @DanBron I was surprised by that too. I only added the Semitics.SE ad because I saw this happened (and got upvoted) last year. Obviously English resources will be more helpful here.

Comment: Are there any legality issues with making ads for off-site resources? Like, could I make an ad going to the OED's page about getting access through a library?

Comment: @1006a No, there are no issues with that. We’ve done it before. But the OED specifically won’t help most people because most people aren’t subscribers and so wont be able to read it.

Comment: @DanBron That's why I specifically mentioned linking to "**the page about getting access through a library**".

Comment: @1006a Given the mindset engendered by the Internet, and especially displayed by people who use Google and end up on EL&U, I think linking to a single page saying “here’s a hoop you have to jump through, likely involving actual footwork and a day or two, before you get your answer” is likely not the best use of that ad space. I’d prefer a tool people can use immediately, like OneLook.com (which also doesn’t create the perception of bias towards any single dictionary).

Comment: @DanBron I wasn't thinking of it in terms of "go here instead of asking a question" so much as "if you're wondering what this OED is that gets cited all over ELU, or just love English and want a huge mega-resource to play around with, here's one possible way that you might be able to get access." It was also just an off-the-top-of-my-head example, not something I have all drafted and ready to go. If I bother to make an ad and you don't like it, though, feel free to downvote. And/or make an ad for OneLook (I'd probably upvote that).

Comment: @1006a I understand. Thanks clarifying. I’ll probably make one for OneLook

Answer (score 12):

[image: English Language Learners]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Explore the roots of English at the Latin Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Akkadian, Amharic, Arabic, Hebrew, Phoenician, Punic, Syriac, Tigrinya? Support Semitics.SE!]

Comment: This one perhaps could also mention other languages.

Comment: @Mithrandir you are right. I created a whole new one for here and ELL.

Comment: @Keelan I think it was closed for not being a viable site. And you just made the same site again?

Comment: @NVZ see https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27954/72809 for reasons why it could work this time; last time we lacked Arabic-speaking audience which we may attract better this time because the Arabic proposal has just been closed as well. However, also see the answer by curiousdannii on that link for changing the scope to *dead written languages*. In that case, this add will be adapted of course.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Interested in applications of language?]

Comment: Copied from [last year](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10009/87724); ad mostly designed by [BESW](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/423/17).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Visit Writing Q&A]

Comment: What’s with the crossed out bit in he bottom? Do you want to show the crosses out bit in the actual ad in the sidebar? If not, should it be cropped out?

Comment: @DanBron oh, that's meant to be a pen.  I'll take this feedback back to the designer, thanks.

Comment: Oh wow! Now that I see it, I can’t unsee it! But I couldn’t see it at all before. Amazing. Blue and black or yellow and gold!

Comment: @DanBron does this work better?

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer! Also the overlap is more fun and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Constructed Languages SE]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: And, As Is Tradition, I have downvotes this example again this year. Rarely do I see the automated twitter feed promote the posts that make me proudest of EL&U, and frequently I see it tweet out the kinds of questions which are most likely to bring exactly the kind of attention I *don’t* want to the site.

Comment: There may be scope for removing the automatic posting and implementing a system similar to closure/deletion (where a number of positive votes causes a tweet). Perhaps I'll write a question...