# Does EL&U have a newsletter?

Tags: discussion, support

I was browsing the various sites on Stack Exchange and noticed some having a "Subscribe to newsletter" button.

Does such a thing exist here? Are there reasons why there isn't one, in the case there isn't?

Comment: I’m not aware of one. It would almost certainly be something the Meta community would be responsible for producing, so if it did exist, I’d expect to know about it. Sounds like one of those early ideas SE had for all new sites, like the per-site blog, which also bit the dust. If that’s the case, and I had to guess *why* we don’t have one: for the same reason the blogs never took off. Not enough people interested in doing the work of putting it together.

Comment: @DanBron From what I can tell much of the content could be automated, such as "Top questions of the week" or something of the likes.

Comment: That’s not much of a newsletter.. you can get that right now on the site in one click (Top Questions > Week).

Comment: @DanBron I was thinking more as a reminder or summary for people who haven't come around to visiting the page in a while.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: There used to be a blog (a place for community written articles , longer expositions on topics of users' choices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa, ELU *does* have a newsletter, and, as you suggested, it *is* automated.

[image: preview of EL&U newsletter]

You can subscribe to the EL&U —
or any other SE site — newsletter here:

https://stackexchange.com/newsletters

EL&U can be found under “Culture”, in the right column. You may have to click “show more Culture sites” at the bottom of that column. Or you can use the search field at the top left and type in “English”.

---

<sub>In case it’s of interest, I tracked this down by going to [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com), searching for “newsletters” (plural in the hope to find only posts about newsletters for all sites), clicked the first result, saw the tag [newsletter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newsletter), clicked on it, sorted by “votes”, and found this MSE post: *[Weekly site newsletters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters)*.</sub>

Comment: Wow, that's a rabbit-hole. Any idea why it's hidden there?

Comment: @ALambentEye Do you mean why the URL is https://stackexchange.com/newsletters or why you have to click an extra button on that page to get ELU to show up? For the former, no real idea. It’s as good a url as any, I suppose. It’s top-level at least, and descriptive, so Google should like it. For the latter: there are hundreds of sites in the network, many more than can be displayed in a screenfull. So there has to be an ordering and a “display more” mechanism of some kind. Looks like the ordering is category, then alphabetic. That’s fair, though I think top billing might be better for big sites.

Comment: I was wondering more why it can't be found on the EL&U site.

Comment: @ALambentEye Oh, I dunno. I’d never heard of the newsletters before you brought it up. Where do you find it on other sites? Right now the design team *has* asked us for any changes we’d like to see in the site’s design, so we have an opportunity to put a link somewhere more prominent, if we think it’s worthwhile.

Comment: I originally spotted it over on [the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ALambentEye Yeah but where on the site? How did you find it on that site? Where is it mentioned or displayed?

Comment: Under the watch/ignore tags to the right of the page.

Comment: @ALambentEye That sounds like the “[community promotion ad](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/community-promotion-ads-2018)” space. I double-checked WB’s Meta site, and it sure looks like they’re using the community promotion ad space to [advertise the newsletter](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6530/21537). Not entirely sure though, it *might* be a completely separate ad area. But the Promotion one is the only one we (the Meta community) have control over.

Comment: @ALambentEye the [Newsletter setting](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/email/newsletters/current) is accessible from User Profile -> Edit Profile & Settings -> Newsletters (under Email Settings)